# Getting scroll in jquery-ui dialog when using datepicker in IE 11

Tags: html, jsp, jquery-ui

I am getting scrolls when using jQuery date/time picker only in IE11 how to eliminate them please help me.

FYI: Please see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden;` in your CSS.

Comment: In other dialogs i have more elements in that case using 'overflow:hidden' may hide those params

Comment: put only in that box where you need

Comment: you can make one class and put that where you need